# openCV C++ find Contours

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to get the coordinates of the contours from my picture. And i want to save it as a .txt document.

First of all i created:

```
vector<vector<cv:Pont> >extract<cv::Mat &binaryImage){
vector<vector<cv::Point> > coordinatesContours;
cv::findContours(binaryImage, coordinatesContours,  CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
return coordinatesContours;
}
```

And i call the function in my Main:

```
oTest.extract(binaryImage);
```

And now i want to export the coordinates as an output into a .txt

My function:

```
void Export(vector<vector<cv::Point> > coordinatesContours){

string json;
json = "{\n\t\t \"vertices\" : [\n\t\t\t\t";


for(int i=0; i< coordinatesContours.size; i++)
    for(int j=0; i< coordinatesContours.size; j++)
        cout << i << "(" << coordinatesContours[i][j].x << ", " << coordinatesContours[i][j].y << ")" << endl;
```

but how can i finish my fuction??

And how to call it in my Main??

Please Help
thx

Comment: Why your first function is incomplete? It would be helpful if you post all the function, no matter if you are using it in a class

Comment: By the way in the function you posted, you have a misspeling error here: `vector<vector<cv:Pont> >extract<cv::Mat &binaryImage){` you need to change `Pont` by `Point`

Answer (score 0):

Well I have to say that you can add the Export function directly in the Extract function. You should use `fstream` to export the points here an example:

```
#indlude fstream
// edit : typo corrected Pont -> Point
... vector<vector<cv::Point> >extract<cv::Mat &binaryImage){
    vector<vector<cv::Point> > coordinatesContours;
    cv::findContours(binaryImage, coordinatesContours,  CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

fstream export_file;
export_file.open("Some_Name.txt",std::ios::out);

for(int i=0; i< coordinatesContours.size; i++)
    for(int j=0; i< coordinatesContours[i].size; j++)
        export_file << "Contour: " << i << ", Point: " << j << ",(" << coordinatesContours[i][j].x << ", " << coordinatesContours[i][j].y << ")" << endl;
export_file.close();

}
```

Comment: i tried but i doesn*t work. Is that possible that my find contours function has a mistake?

Comment: what version of opencv are you using?